# Datetime conversion independent of system date format

Tags: c#

`Convert.ToDateTime("16/12/2015")` works fine in my code if system date format is `dd/MM/yyyy` but if system format is `12/16/2015` ie. `MM/dd/yyyy` gives error.

I want to make this code work independent of system date format.How can i do it?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(string)` overload uses your `CurrentCulture` settings *by default*. That means your current culture uses `dd/MM/yyyy` as a short date format, not `MM/dd/yyyy`. It can't use both formats since it _can_ creates ambiguous cases for example for `01/02/2015` string be 1st February or 2nd January. All `DateTime` parsing methods uses an `IFormatProvider`. Specifying an `IFormatProvider` would be better but does not solve parsing both format with correctly. You can use `ParseExact` methods to specify your format for example.

Comment: Use a universal format, such as "2009-05-01T07:54:59.9843750-04:00".

Comment: how to use universal format?

Comment: tried using parse exact method but still the same error error.i just want irrespective of system date format convert.todatetime("dd/MM/yyyy") should work.

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact("31/01/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", null)`